# Difference between the implementation?

Tags: algorithm, debugging

So recently I stumbled across a query i.e.

code 1:

```
for(long i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    long j = (fullsum - 2*(sum -i))/2;
    if(j >= m+1 && j <=n) {
         swaps++;
    }
}
```

code 2:

```
for(long i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
     for(long j = m+1; j <=n ; j++) {
         if(sum - i + j == fullsum - sum -j + i) {
              swaps++;
              break;
         }
     }
}
```

Where fullsum = n*(n+1)/2, sum = m*(m+1)/2

1 <= N <= 10^9

1 <= M < N

Now my question here is that both the codes seem identical to me(logic wise) but Code 2 is giving correct output while code 1 is not.

Can anyone please tell me the difference between the codes, further why code2 is giving the correct output while code1 is not and what is the correct way of implementing code 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting `if(sum - i + j == fullsum - sum -j + i)`, we get

```
if(2*j == fullsum - 2*(sum-i))
```

In the first code, the value you are assigning to `j` is

```
long j = (fullsum - 2*(sum -i))/2;
```

The issue is pretty clear: division truncation is causing the incorrect results. Let's say that `fullsum - 2*(sum-i) = 45` for some case, and `j=22`. Now, the second condition will be false, since `2*j != fullsum - 2*(sum-i)`.
However, for the first condition, `(fullsum - 2*(sum -i))/2` has a value of `45/2 = 22` (floor division), so the condition `j = (fullsum - 2*(sum -i))/2` will be counted as a valid result when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong question. Now i ve made necessary changes. Sorry for the inconvenience.